# Como passar um arquivot .txt para uma função

Tags: c, arquivo

Gostaria de criar uma função que receba um arquivo `.txt` e faça alguma coisa com ela, mas não sei como definir os parâmetros de envio e recebimento, ou se devo fazer passagem de parâmetro por referencia.

Envio do arquivo para função: `funcaoRecebeArquivo(arquivo);`

Não sei ao certo o que deve ser colocado dentro do parênteses quando chamo a função e envio o arquivo.
Um esboço de código abaixo:

```
funcaoRecebeArquivo(arquivo)
{
    //Receber o arquivo e fazer algo com ele aqui dentro
}

int main ()
{

    FILE *sensvalid;

    if ((sensvalid = fopen("X10Map.txt","r")) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Nao consegui abrir o arquivo X10MAP.");
        return 2;
    }

    funcaoRecebeArquivo(arquivo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta é de como definir o cabeçalho da função que recebe o arquivo ? Se for o caso seria algo como `void funcaoRecebeArquivo (FILE *arquivo)`

Comment: Exato, também preciso chamar a função dentro do main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função que recebe o arquivo tem de receber um parâmetro do tipo `FILE*`, e normalmente será do tipo `void` a menos que queira retornar um valor especifico para o `main`.

No `main` quando chama a função tem de passar o arquivo que abriu para leitura, que no seu caso é o `sensvalid`.

Exemplo do código com essa estrutura:

```
void utilizarArquivo(FILE *arquivo)
{
    //fazer qualquer coisa com o arquivo, como por exemplo fread()
}

int main ()
{

    FILE *sensvalid;

    if ((sensvalid = fopen("X10Map.txt","r")) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Nao consegui abrir o arquivo X10MAP.");
        return 2;
    }

    utilizarArquivo(sensvalid);//o parametro a passar é sensvalid, que representa o arquivo
    return 0;
}
```

Para ler informação do arquivo normalmente utilizará [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) ou [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), ao passo que para escrever o mais comum é [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).